# Proof $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} = 1 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} = 1 $, is my proof correct?

Pf:
Define $ f(x) = \frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} $

Given $ \epsilon \gt 0 $, Choose $ M = \epsilon + 100 $

Suppose $ x \gt M $, Therefore:

$ \left|\frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} - 1\right| \lt  \left|x - 5 - 1\right| = | x - 6 | = x - 6 \lt \epsilon   \Rightarrow x \lt \epsilon + 6 \Rightarrow x \lt \epsilon + 100 $

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists M \gt 0$ such that $ \forall x \gt M, \left|f(x) - 1\right| \lt \epsilon $

$ \Rightarrow $

$  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} = 1 $

Comment: Why do you claim that $ \left|\frac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} - 1\right| \leqslant  \left|x - 5 - 1\right|$?

Comment: Note $\dfrac{x - 5}{\sqrt{x^{2} - 10x + 24}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac1{(x-5)^2}}}$

Comment: Personally, I like the approach of @Henry.  A simpler but less elegant approach is that for $x \geq 7$, you have that $$(x - 5)^2 > x^2 - 10x + 24 > (x - 6)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I see two significant errors.

The denominator of your original expression disappears in the first step.  The denominator is key to this limit, since without it, you would be taking the limit of $x-5$, which diverges to infinity.

Instead, you could either multiply the numerator and denominator by the radical, or find upper and lower bounds on the denominator.

Second, you seem to introduce $\varepsilon$ at the end of the first part of the computation.  In fact, $x-6$ is likely to be a large number and not near $\varepsilon$.

Logically, this doesn’t make sense since it is possible for a false statement to imply a true statement, which is what happens here.  You want to derive that your expression is less that $\epsilon$, not assume it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your proof is not correct.

One contradictory step in your proof is that you "suppose $x>M=(\epsilon+100)$" and end up with $x<\epsilon+100$.

You correctly identify that one needs to estimate the quantity $$\left|\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{x^2-10x+24}}-1\right|\tag{1}
$$ but nevertheless give an unhelpful estimate:
$$
\left|\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{x^2-10x+24}}-1\right|<|x-5-1|\tag{2}
$$
While this is true (for large $x$), it would not give you the desired proof.
You need to bound the left-hand side by a "small" quantity when $x$ is big, which would lead you to the $\epsilon$. But the one in (2) is *too* large.

---

A direct $\epsilon$-$\delta$ type proof is not necessary unless one is explicitly told to do so (for a purpose of an exercise). Instead, you could approach by limit laws. Observing that for sufficiently large $x$,
$$
\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{x^2-10x+24}}=\frac{1-\frac{5}{x}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{24}{x^2}}}
$$
Now you can apply the quotient law and continuity of the square root function to conclude that the limit is $1$.